# How can I convert this Ajax query to http client request in Angular 8?

Tags: ajax, angular, httpclient, angular8

I have a request in ajax, like this:

```
  var data = {
    REQUEST: 'GetFeatureInfo',
    SERVICE: 'WMS',
    VERSION: '1.1.1',
    LAYERS: layerName,
    STYLES: '',
    FORMAT: 'image/png',
    INFO_FORMAT:'application/json',
    BGCOLOR: '0xFFFFFF',
    TRANSPARENT: 'TRUE',
    SRS: 'EPSG:' + mapSRID,
    BBOX: xmin + "," + ymin + "," + xmax + "," + ymax,
    WIDTH: map.width,
    HEIGHT: map.height,
    QUERY_LAYERS: layerName,
    X: screenPoint.x.toFixed(0),
    Y: screenPoint.y.toFixed(0)
  };
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: "application/json",
    complete: function (data) {
      callBack(data);
    }
  });
}
```

I want to convert to angular by using http client get method. How can I do that.

My solution but reponse: ok: false

```
  getInfo() {
    const params = {
      SERVICE: 'WMS',
      VERSION: '1.1.1',
      ...
    };

    this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms', params).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

The response:
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&EQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=topp:states&LAYERS=topp:states&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG:4326&STYLES=&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=-113.8623046875,42.4072265625,-104.9853515625,51.2841796875"
ok: false

To more clear, I'm want to convert URL get request to http client get method request in Angular 8:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?service=wms&version=1.1.1&request=GetCapabilities

Comment: What have you tried so far? Making http requests in Angular is *extremely* well documented. What specific part are you struggling with?

Comment: I have tried but when I using Postman it work very well, but when I using get method the status return is 200 and ok is false.

Comment: *What* have you tried?

Comment: This all sounds like very relevant information to your question

Comment: const params = {
      'key':'value'
    };

    this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wms', params).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });

Comment: Can you add to your post, and explain what `{ 'key':'value' }` is meant to be

Comment: const params = {
      SERVICE: 'WMS',
      VERSION: '1.1.1',
      EQUEST: 'GetFeatureInfo',
      FORMAT: 'image/png',
      TRANSPARENT: 'true',
      QUERY_LAYERS: 'topp:states',
      LAYERS: 'topp:states',
      exceptions: 'application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage',
      INFO_FORMAT: 'text/html',

Comment: to more clear, I'm want to create request like this: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?
service=wms&
version=1.1.1&
request=GetCapabilities by using http client get method in angular 8.

Comment: Please put all of this in the question instead of the comment chain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject HttpClient to in your service.

```
this.http.post(url , data).subscribe(response => {
 console.log(response);
}) //post request if you have to send data

this.http.get(url).subscribe(response => {
 console.log(response);
})//get if you want data
```

Ajax internally append data you send with the request to the url string. So in order to do that using angular, you need to use `HttpParams`

```
let params = new HttpParams().set("paramName",paramValue).set("paramName2", paramValue2); //Create new HttpParams

this.http.get(url, {headers: headers, params: params});
```

Comment: He wants to send body with GET request

Comment: syntax errror:   ERROR in src/app/services/query-geoserver.service.ts(38,68): error TS2559: Type '{ SERVICE: string; VERSION: string; EQUEST:

Comment: Get request does'nt have body

Comment: if you want to send data,simply use POST instead

Comment: No, it;s required

Comment: you can use headers to send data with get request but on the server side you need to retrieve data from the header as get request does'nt have a body

Comment: please refer to my edited answer and see if it works

Comment: I'm trying your method.

Answer (score 0):

In your data you have EQUEST instead of REQUEST